# Discord bot conversation

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot that will run a function based on questions asked, of which multiple are yes/no questions. Answering "yes" will do a certain function while "no" should end the question. 
I do not want the bot to run a random function every time it reads "yes".
The only solution I could think of is once the question has been asked (based on a word trigger), the user gets stuck in a loop where the bot will not respond to any trigger other than "yes" / "no". 
If yes, the related function will run. 
If no, the user gets out of the loop and is able to trigger another question. 
Other than yes/no, the bot will say "please reply with yes or no" 
How can I code this in node.js/discord.js?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a command that the users must run to initiate this conversation...I recommend referencing this in the [discord.js official documentaion](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) that talks about `awaitMessages`. Basically, you could use this followed by a series of `.then()` and `if statements` that will take the user down multiple paths based on their answers that can be filtered out.

If this is a default function of the bot without needing a trigger command, I recommend you tread carefully in this area as something like this could be quite spammy.

An example:

```js
message.channel.send('Is this a great bot?').then(async (start) => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { maxMatches: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time']}).then(async (collected) => {
                if (collected.first().content === "yes") {} else if (collected.first().content === "no") {}
            })
```

You can filter messages with the `filter` or another way so that `yes/no` are the only acceptable answers.